# Trouble with finding length of list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm having trouble finding the length of a list. I know how to deal with lists such as say `[a,b,c,d]` or `[a,b,[],d]` or even `[a,[[[]]],c,[]]` each of which have a length of 4. The problem I'm having is trying to figure out the length of the list in a case like this `[a,[b,c],d]`. There are 4 elements, but when I run my code, it'll print 3. It considers the inner list `[b,c]` as a single element and I'm not sure how to count those separately.

Here's what I have:

```
% this is the base case
mylen([],0).

% case where element is a single atom like a or []
mylen([_|T],Len) :- atom(_),Len is Len1+1.

% case that *should* deal with sublists [b,c]
mylen([[_|TH]|T],Len) :- mylen(TH,Len1), Len is Len1+1.

% general case
mylen([_|T],Len):- mylen(T,Len1),Len is Len1+1.
```

I hope my question is clear. Thank you!

Ps. I looked at other posts concerning this, but couldn't find any solutions to this specific problem.

Comment: What are the things that you count as elements, really? It seems that an empty list should be counted: you claim that `[a,b,[],d]` has length 4. But on the other hand, an empty list has a length of 0, right? How do you decide what you should count and what not?

Comment: I consider an empty list if it has no elements. For example: [] is an empty list, but if there is an empty list within a list like [[]] or in the example you said [a,b,[],d] the empty list is an element of the bigger list.

Comment: The "length" is usually a sum of the lengths of the parts, but not in your case. What you say is: the length of `[]` is 0, but the length of `[[]]` is 1. Then, the length of `[a,[]]` is 2, and the length of `[a,[b]]` is 2, and the length of `[a,[[b]]]` is 2 (right?), so the length of `[]` is equal to the length of `[b]` is equal to the length of `[[]]` is equal to the length of `[[b]]`.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd clauses of your predicate throw away the tail `T` altogether, so these won't be counted in your solution. As CapelliC points out, `atom(_)` is always false. The head of your 2nd and 4th clause are identical, so these cases aren't distinguished. The 2nd, 3rd, and 4th clauses all ignore the head of the list (via `_`) and therefore don't consider what it looks like and don't count it at all in the resulting length. You need to think carefully and logically about what your rules mean.

Comment: As another clue, you really only have 3 cases: (1) the first argument is `[]`, (2) the first argument is is `[H|T]` where `H` is an *atom* (keep in mind that `atom([])` is true), and (3) the first argument is `[H|T]` where `H` is a list (or otherwise written, `[[H|TH]|T]`). And you have to make sure the solution contains length contributions from all of the components of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the fact that you need to treat the head of the list in a special way when it is a non-empty list. So for example:

```
strangelen([], 0).
strangelen([H|T], Len) :-
    (   H = [_|_] % head is a non-empty list
    ->  strangelen(H, LenH)
    ;   LenH = 1
    ),
    strangelen(T, LenT),
    Len is LenH + LenT.
```

And then:

```
?- strangelen([a,b,c,d], Len).
Len = 4.

?- strangelen([a,b,[],d], Len).
Len = 4.

?- strangelen([a,[[[]]],c,[]], Len).
Len = 4.

?- strangelen([a,[b,c],d], Len).
Len = 4.

?- strangelen([[]], Len).
Len = 1.

?- strangelen([[[b,c]]], Len).
Len = 2.
```

This solution does not work for a first argument that is not a proper list (try `?- strangelen(List, Len).`)

Answer (score 1):

```
?- atom(_).
false.
```

Then the second clause it's useless, will always fail. You should not ignore the 'shape' of the list' head, since it could be a list. This problem also appears in the third clause.

Comment: When I try to make it atom(H) for the head. I get an instantiation error: uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2) That's why I made it atom(_), although I know this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Len1 is unknown, maybe your clause should be `mylen([H|_],1) :- atom(H).`, but this show the misunderstanding: now it's ignoring the tail...