# Finding the length of lists within a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

For example:

```
count_blocks([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],C).
C=[3,3,2]
```

I know that I can find the length of a list with:

```
len([], LenResult):-
    LenResult is 0.

len([X|Y], LenResult):-
    len(Y, L),
    LenResult is L + 1.
```

but not sure how to calculate list lengths within a list. The outer list length will always be 3 (with the possibility of empty inner lists).

Comment: Try to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002906/trouble-with-finding-length-of-list-in-prolog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write all the predicates yourself you can do it like this:

```
len([], 0).
len([_|Y], LenResult):-
    len(Y, L),
    LenResult is L + 1.

count_blocks([],[]).
count_blocks([H|T],[N|L]):-
    len(H,N),
    count_blocks(T,L).

?- count_blocks([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],C).
C = [3, 3, 2].
```

`count_blocks/2` works with the same principle as `len/2`. As long as there is at least one sublist `H` in the inputlist, calculate the length `N` of sublist `H` and put it as head element of the return list `L`. You get `L` by asking the same query for the rest list: `count_blocks(T,L)`. If the inputlist is empty, the list of sublist-length is empty as well: `count_blocks([],[]).`

Comment: This was a perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Joe ^^ you can accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark left of the answer below the upvote button ^^

Answer (score 2):

You should perform a mapping with length. You can map with [**`maplist/3`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3), so you can work with:

```
count_blocks(L, R) :-
    maplist(length, L, R).
```